# How to redirect users with different roles to their login pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, auth0

I'm really n

```js
export const logUserIn = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`${login}/login`, payload);
    const userData = jwtDecode(data.token);
    if (userData.roles.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('No permissions');
    }

    const userDataJson = JSON.stringify(userData.roles[0]);

    localStorage.setItem('Ftoken', data.token);
    localStorage.setItem('FlairRole', userDataJson);

    window.location = `/${userData.roles[0].role.toLowerCase()}/home`;

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message === 'Request failed with status code 401') {
      notification.error({
        message: 'Error',
        description: 'Sorry Hero, email or password is wrong...',
      });
    }
    if (e.message === 'Network Error') {
      notification.error({
        message: 'Network Error',
        description:
          'Sorry Hero, seems something wrong with your connection...',
      });
    }
    if (e.message === 'No permissions') {
      notification.error({
        message: 'Unauthorized',
        description:
          "Sorry Hero, but seems you don't access. Please, contact out team to know more about Founders Lair marketplace",
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
};

export const getMyProfile = async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('Ftoken');
  if (token) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${login}/profiles/me`, config);
    return data;
  }
  return null;
};

export const logUserOut = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('Ftoken');
  localStorage.removeItem('FlairRole');
  window.location = '/login';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

ew to react, and need your to make sense of a problem.
In the code above, is my userService.js file.

The problem here is that I want to be able to redirect users with roles > 1 to a "continue as" page that I have already built.

I tried to stop event default and push the "continue as" page it didn't work.
I parsed the data in app router and tried a conditional, it also didn't work.

please assist me.